# Se puede responder o no a una pregunta sin iniciar con “No, no...”

Tags: gramática

Yo sé que cuando alguien responda a una pregunta, gramaticalmente tiene que usar "no" dos veces.

"*No es muy amable, verdad? - **No**, no lo es*"

"*¿Siempre estudias? - **No**, nunca estudio.*"

¿Pero en la práctica a veces se puede responder a una pregunta sin duplicar "no"? Sería como:

"*No es muy amable, ¿verdad? - No lo es*"

"*¿Siempre estudias? - Nunca estudio.*"

"*¿No tienes ninguna duda? - No tengo ninguna.*"

Por ejemplo, en una película de Hollywood llamada "Taken" vi lo siguiente:

"*Ya no es una niña ¿verdad? - Supongo que no.*"

Por si es posible responder sin duplicar "no", ¿esto sucede frecuente o aun así se usa "no" dos veces en la mayoría de los casos al responder a una pregunta?

P.S. Por adelantado agradezco que corrijan errores en mi pregunta en caso de que los haya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongamos que hablas inglés...

Cuando yo aprendí inglés me decían que a preguntas tipo 'is she Ella?' iban respuestas de tipo 'no, she is not'. Sin embargo, cuando he viajado he visto que nadie habla así. Pues esto es igual, con algún matiz.
"No es muy amable, ¿verdad? - No lo es" está bien dicho, el primer no niega, o incluso podrías decir no a secas.

"¿Siempre estudias? - Nunca estudio." Aquí me falta el no, sin embargo en ciertos contextos el no se puede cambiar por otra cosa... por ejemplo 'la verdad es que nunca estudio' denotando duda al ser sincero.

"¿No tienes ninguna duda? - No tengo ninguna.". En esta yo diría no sin más o 'de momento no' dando la posibilidad de poder tener dudas mas adelante.

"Ya no es una niña ¿verdad? - Supongo que no." Suena bien